# How to Broadcast Sum Vector and Tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, tensor, array-broadcasting

Suppose we have:

- row vector `V` of shape `(F,1)`, and
- 4-D tensor `T` of shape `(N, F, X, Y)`.

As a concrete example, let `N, F, X, Y` = `2, 3, 2, 2`. Let `V = [v0, v1,v2]`.

Then, I want to element-wise add `v0` to the inner 2x2 matrix `T[0,0]`, `v1` to `T[0,1]`, and `v2` to `T[0,2]`. Similarly, I want to add `v0` to `T[1,0]`, `v1` to `T[1,1]`, and `v2` to `T[1,2]`.

So at the "innermost" level, the addition between the 2x2 matrix and a scalar, e.g. `T[0,0] + v0`, uses broadcasting to element-wise add `v0`. Then what I'm trying to do is apply that more generally to each inner 2x2.

I've tried using `np.einsum()` and `np.tensordot()`, but I couldn't figure out what each of those functions was actually doing on a more fundamental level, so I wanted to ask for a more step-by-step explanation of how this computation might be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To multiply**: You can simply translate your text into indices names of `eisnum` and it will take care of broadcasting:

```
TV = np.einsum('ijkl,j->ijkl',T,V)
```

**To add**: Simply add dimensions to your `V` using `None` to match up last two dimensions of `T` and broadcasting will take care of the rest:

```
TV = T + V[:,None,None]
```

Example input/output that shows the desired behavior of your output for adding:

T:

```
[[[[7 4]
   [5 9]]

  [[0 3]
   [2 6]]

  [[7 6]
   [1 1]]]


 [[[8 0]
   [8 7]]

  [[2 6]
   [9 2]]

  [[8 6]
   [4 9]]]]
```

V:

```
[0 1 2]
```

TV:

```
[[[[ 7  4]
   [ 5  9]]

  [[ 1  4]
   [ 3  7]]

  [[ 9  8]
   [ 3  3]]]


 [[[ 8  0]
   [ 8  7]]

  [[ 3  7]
   [10  3]]

  [[10  8]
   [ 6 11]]]]
```

Comment: `einsum` here is summing pairs of products, right? what could we do if we wanted instead to add each element in `v`,rather than multiply? for example, by adding, the first 2x2 would be `[[4 6] [0 3]` instead of `[[0 0] [0 0]]`

Comment: @AisforAmbition I miss-read the question. Yes you can. I added an edit to cover adding too. Thank you for catching the difference.

Comment: The add method makes a lot of sense. You're basically "nesting" each `v_i` into the desired location to be broadcasted with the 2x2 matrices. Thanks!